# Looping Issues in Java

Tags: java, arrays, loops, user-interface, count

I'm making a simple currency converter GUI (nothing fancy) as I am going to try and incorporate live exchange rate updates for each time the user opens the application. When creating the layout, I have decided to simple convert 3 currencies (GBP, USD and EUR). I have the respective flags in 2 columns, each column has one of the 3 flags. One column is for the user to select the initial currency and the other is the desired currency to exchange to; as seen below [image: Basic layout with the flags in columns, 'From' and 'To']

I have created a String array which contains the words "Pounds", "Dollars" and "Euros" and I am wanting to put these labels to the left of the flags (for clarity of the application for the user as not every user may know which currency belongs to which country.

I created a loop which would create a label and assign it to the left of the flags, it is supposed to make a "pound" label, then a "Dollar" then a "euro" each time traversing the Y axis south so that they aligns with the flags and it will then reset the array count to go back to the correct string, move along the x-axis and repeat it again. It is however not doing this at all, the only result I get is the text "Pounds " to the left of the first United Kingdom flag; as seen below:

[image: As you can see, i simply get one label]

below is my code if anyone can see as to why this is happening.

**This is the code which adds the flags to the panel**

```
    addToMain(GBP1, mainPage, 100,100,100,100); //alligns a United Kingdom Flag to left Column
    addToMain(GBP2, mainPage, 375,100,100,100); //alligns a United Kingdom Flag to right Column
    addToMain(USD1, mainPage, 100,200,100,100); //alligns a United States Flag to left Column
    addToMain(USD2, mainPage, 375,200,100,100); //alligns a United States Flag to right Column
    addToMain(EUR1, mainPage, 100,300,100,100); //alligns a European Union Flag to left Column
    addToMain(EUR2, mainPage, 375,300,100,100); //alligns a European Union Flag to right Column
```

**This is the loop which should add the text labels to the left of the flags**

```
    currencyName = new String [] {"Pounds", "Dollars", "Euros"};

    for(int i = 0; i <= 7; i++)
    {
        int count = 0; //declares a counter for the position in the currencyName array to grab the correct text for label
        xLabelAlign = 50;
        yLabelAlign = 100;

        if(count == 3)
          {
              count = 0; //resets to create both columns of labels in the application moves to the next column.
              xLabelAlign = 325;
              yLabelAlign = 100;
          }

          JLabel temp = new JLabel(currencyName[count]); //creates a new label and names it the string at position count
          temp.setFont(new Font("SERIF", Font.BOLD, 20));
          temp.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
          addToMain(temp, mainPage, xLabelAlign, yLabelAlign ,100,100); //adds it to the panel 

          yLabelAlign +=100; //moves position ready for the next text label.
          count++;  //grabs the next label in the currencyName string array.         

    }
```

**This is the method which adds things to the panel. I have used the set bounds methods to add things to the panel so i can position them where i want easily**

```
  private void addToMain(JComponent c, JPanel p, int x, int y, int w, int h)
{
    c.setBounds(x,y,w,h);
    p.add(c);
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: R.I.P. Layout Manager

Comment: Forgot `setBounds(x, y, w, h)`, use `LayoutManager` instead. Here is the [Oracle tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) :)

Comment: you should use `LayoutManager` , you are only programming to your screen in this way ;)

Comment: hmm, something tells me i should look into layout manager :P, cheers guys, im using border layout for the title and status bar, BorderLayout.CENTRE is the panel with the flags (i.e. mainPage variable), i didnt setBounds everything, might have made a few people on here physically sick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fast solution: Move your `int count = 0; xLabelAlign = 50; yLabelAlign = 100;` out of the `for` loop. Loop in the range of [0,5].

Good solution: [Java layouts tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html)

Comment: I think the same goes for `xLabelAlign`.

Comment: Edited. Anyway I hope the author will be able to fix the other code by himself cause I doubt that all of these numbers are correct and will place the labels in correct positions.

Comment: i had to move xLabelAlign, yLabelAlign and my count outside the loop and it got this working. I will however look into LayoutManagers now to see if i can use a more practical design 

thanks to both of you for the help :)

http://imgur.com/h3OjbZZ

Comment: You should fix the loop range too. Even on the screenshot it is visible that Pounds and Dollars in the second column are added twice.